# Java try-with-resource when resource is inside non-Closable wrapper

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Suppose, I have a method returning an instance of Result class:

```
public class Result {
    pubilc InputStream content;
    public long contentLength;
}
```

I want to work to work safely with this InputStream, but obviously, since Result does not impoement Closeable, I can't just write something like this:

```
try (Result result = getResult()) {
    ...
}
```

One of possible solutions is to make Result Closeable:

```
public class Result implements Closeable {
    public InputStream content;
    public long contentLength;

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        content.close();
    }
}
...
// this should work now
try (Result result = getResult()) {
    ...
} catch (IOException) {
    ...
}
```

But what if I can't modify Result (or don't want to)?

Another way is to call close() manually, but it is kind of bulky:

```
Result result = null;
try {
    result = getResult();
    ...
} catch (...) {
    ...
} finally {
    if (result != null) {
        result.content.close();
    }
}
```

I also thought about something like this:

```
Result result = getResult();
try (InputStream stream = result.content) {
   ...
}
```

But it will fail if exception will thrown by getResult().

So my question is: are there any other options in this situation?

Comment: *But what if I can't modify Result (or don't want to)?* than you wont make it autocloseable and try-with-resources is not for you.

Comment: Theoreticly you could wrap iputstream to close underlying stream on error and rethrow(or swallow) the exception,

Comment: Note that if `getResult()` thows an exception, you do not have `Result` object and therefore you have nothing to close.

Comment: Easiest and proper solution is to make this class Closeable.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a factory method to create an `Autocloseable` wrapper.

```
public Autocloseable autocloseable(Result result) {
    return new Autocloseable() {
        public void close() {
            result.content.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and then use try-with-resources like this

```
Result result = getResult();
try (Autocloseable ac = autocloseable(result)) {
    doStuffWith(result);
}
```

Or, of course, overengineer

```
class AutoclosingWrapper<T> implements Autocloseable {
    private T object;
    private Function<T, Autocloseable> autocloseable;

    public AutoclosingWrapper(Supplier<T> c, Function<T, Autocloseable> a) {
        this(c.get(), a);
    }
    public AutoclosingWrapper(T t, Function<T, Autocloseable> a) {
        object = t;
        autocloseable = a;
    }
    public T getObject() {
        return object;
    }
    public void close() {
        autocloseable.apply(object).close();
    }
}
```

which is called with

```
try (AutoclosingWrapper<Result> wrapper = new AutoclosingWrapper(this::getResult, r -> r.content)) {
    doStuffWith(wrapper.getObject());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not nice, but obvious:

```
Result result = getResult();
try (InputStream content = result.content) {
    ...
}
```

can be turned into

```
Result result;
try (InputStream content = (result = getResult()).content) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Antoniossss you are right, copied for editing, threw my glass over the table, and went for some tissues. Maybe more worth a comment though.